# Another Off-Topic Question?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I hate being stereotypical - but if you dont ask you dont get - and I was pointed here (twice in fact) to [contest my question closure](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72101/1941w-wireless-clients-losing-dhcp-ip-address). Are there any edits I can make to bring this back into the 'on-topic' domain where it can add value for myself and others?

My justification is that the Cisco 1900 series is a [small-branch level equipment type](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/1900-series-integrated-services-routers-isr/index.html), and my question revolves around L2-3 protocols. Admittedly in this instance the 'context' could be considered off-topic, but I would say the question is not (frankly, does anyone care where my 1941W is located? I doubt it).

I would also say there is a middle ground between 'enterprise' networks, small businesses, and consumer level. Whilst Super User is great for consumer level equipment, a lot of questions at this middle level seem to go unanswered.

Having done a fair read through the meta, I haven't exactly got high hopes - but by asking it adds to the statistics of people who have inadvertently stepped out of line and the chance the issues raised in the questions below may be addressed:

[Specifically exclude small business or SMB equipment/networks in "on-topic" description](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/698/specifically-exclude-small-business-or-smb-equipment-networks-in-on-topic-desc)

[Yet another closed question based on the word "home" existing](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1937/yet-another-closed-question-based-on-the-word-home-existing)

I also find it very interesting that - despite being directed here to discuss on/off topic - there are numerous examples [such as this one](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/disagree-with-closed-question) of the meta-question also being downvoted (i.e. off-topic for the off-topic Q&A board!).

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a host problem, which is off-topic (ask about that on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)) because both the router DHCP server process and the WAP still believe the host is connected. It is not the router or WAP dropping the host, but the host dropping the WAP, and we cannot help with a host problem. There could easily be some some wireless interference causing the host to drop the connection, or it could be some other host problem, such as a bad driver, but we cannot help with those types of problems.

The router DHCP server process has already assigned an address to that host, so it really would only respond to a renewal request. Remember that the DHCP servers built into network devices are rather primitive, and possibly a real DHCP server would respond as you would want.

Comment: If this is a host topic - then I agree and apologise - however this affects all hosts, with the common factor being the 1941W/WAP. Potentially with the 1900 series being quite old now, it could still be a host issue (i.e. legacy not being as compatible as I'd like)...but can this question get the benefit of the doubt *until* the nature becomes apparent and then close/relocate as appropriate?